# SFML crashing on mouse collision test Process terminated 255

Tags: c++, sfml

This function seems to crash the application. I commented it out and then the app ran fine. Do you guys see what i'm doing wrong?

`buttons` is a `map` which key is of type `string` and value is of type `sf::sprite`
I have it running in a `while` loop that runs when it's told that the menu is open

```
std::string Menu::buttonPress(sf::RenderWindow* window, sf::Event* event)
{
    while(window->pollEvent(*event))
    {
        if(event->type == sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonPressed)
        {
            sf::Vector2i mousepos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(*window);

            for(auto it: buttons)
            {
                sf::Rect<float> sprite;
                sprite = it.second.getGlobalBounds();
                if(sprite.contains(mousepos.x,mousepos.y))
                {
                    return it.first;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This `function` runs within a while loop.
`window` is a `sf::RenderWindow`.
`event` is a `sf::Event`.

```
if(openmenu)
        {
            options.showMenu(&window); //This draws to the renderwindow

            if(options.buttonPress(&window, &event) == "Exit")
            {
                openmenu = false;
                window.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you certain `window` and `event` point to some valid object?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event that there is no `MouseButtonPressed` event in the event queue, (which I would expect to be the case for the majority of iterations), or if there is, the mouse position is not inside one of your buttons, your function does not return a value, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah shoot i didn't do that cause i was just testing it out. haha i'm an idiot. Thank you very much!